# Microsoft SQL Server 2016 isnt default

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I have currently a project at school where I need to work with a Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (v13) file, but my Visual Studio 2015/2017 Enterprise takes version 12 as default and it wont let me change it. I've tried installing the express edition on it, but that didn't help. I do see that it is installed, but when I installed it I have not changed the key, maby that is the problem. I did found out that in appdata the 12 is present there but the 13 not. I guess that I need to instanciate it but don't know how. Can anyone pls help me?

Comment: How are you connecting to db? show us something

Comment: I cant even open the database file (db.mdf) in Visual Studio, and the connection code is done by the teachers and at other peoples pc's it does work. One of the things I tried as well is installing Visual Studio 2017, and in the instalation I checked that the right version of MSSQL SERVER was selected.

Comment: Then ask your teacher for help. Maybe is something wrong with the instalation. Things you should try. Open SQL Managment Studio and try to connect to db. If you are able to connect then use VS Server Explorer to try connect.